# How to DRY coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, dry

How would one adhere to DRY in this case (the number of accordions could be large):

```
$ ->
  $("#accordion-1").accordion
    autoHeight: false
    navigation: true
$ ->
  $("#accordion-2").accordion
    autoHeight: false
    navigation: true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you can create a function which generate another function by a selector:

```
create = (selector) ->
  $ ->
    $(selector).accordion
      autoHeight: false
      navigation: true
```

then:

```
create "#accordion1"
create "#accordion2"
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know CoffeeScript, but in JS with jQuery, you could say like `$("#accordion-1,#accordion-2").accordion(...)` to affect both elements at once.

Or, you could apply a class to the accordions in your HTML and then say like `$(".accordion").accordion(...)`.  That seems to me the way least likely to cause future grief; you want an accordion, you just give it the appropriate class.  You remove it from the HTML, it's already removed from the list of elements to work with without you having to edit a separate script.

Comment: Thanks cHao, I gave the answer to Jeffery Zhao because he does provide an example of re-factoring coffeescript in this case.  However you are right, and correct that this is a code smell - one should introduce classes for this type of situation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest/shortest solution:

```
$ ->
  $("#accordion-1, #accordion-2").accordion
    autoHeight: no
    navigation: yes
```

Comment: Jeffery Zhao's would allow one to loop over a list in case there are many accordion, while it doesn't answer the 'how to refactor in coffeescript' cHao is correct one should use a class. In coffeescript this is also the simplest.